# Angular always selects the first option in select element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So this is my select (I'm not using the ng-options feature as I need to disable options and I'm using angular 1.3.x, `disable by` feature is in 1.4 afaik)

```
<select class="checkout" 
        ng-model="user.deliveryTime" 
        ng-change="timeUpdate  = true"
        ng-class="{'selected' : user.deliveryTime}" >
  <option value="" disabled selected>Delivery Slot </option>
  <option ng-repeat = "deliveryTime in intervals" 
          ng-disabled="deliveryTime.tooLate" value="{{deliveryTime.time}}">
       {{deliveryTime.time}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Here's how preselect a value for the select

```
config.deliveryTimes(function(m){
  $scope.intervals = m;
  $scope.user.deliveryTime = $scope.intervals[2].time;
});
```

`config.deliveryTimes(callback)` basically makes a HTTP request and back.

Even when I explicitly set the option of the 3rd value of the array, I always get the first option. When I hard-code the options in the select's controller, it still doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Try : `$scope.user.deliveryTime = "" + $scope.intervals[2].time;`

Comment: @MichaelP., still doesn't work

Comment: whats the code inside `config.deliveryTimes`?

Comment: Would you mind making a plunker for this? I'd love to look into a working example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `selected` attribute on the default option and use `ng-selected="user.deliveryTime === deliveryTime.time"` :

```
<select class="checkout" 
        ng-model="user.deliveryTime" 
        ng-change="timeUpdate  = true"
        ng-class="{'selected' : user.deliveryTime}" >
  <option value="" disabled>Delivery Slot </option>
  <option ng-repeat = "deliveryTime in intervals" 
          ng-disabled="deliveryTime.tooLate" value="{{deliveryTime.time}}"
          ng-selected="user.deliveryTime === deliveryTime.time">
       {{deliveryTime.time}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use ng-value instead of value in the option, the selected option is bind to the options set in the ng-model (user.deliverytime)

```
<select class="checkout" 
    ng-model="user.deliveryTime" 
    ng-change="timeUpdate  = true"
    ng-class="{'selected' : user.deliveryTime}" >
<option value="" disabled>Delivery Slot </option>
<option ng-repeat = "deliveryTime in intervals" 
        ng-disabled="deliveryTime.tooLate" ng-value="deliveryTime.time"
        >
     {{deliveryTime.time}}
 </option>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8hKIXwK5i35lczWEtuCw?p=preview